# Problem during Ansible Configuration

Tags: server

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
sudo nano /etc/ansible/hosts
```

Edited the file as:

[Webserver]
   192.168.27.1

[servers]
   host1 ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.27.1
Then

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ansible/group_vars
sudo nano /etc/ansible/group_vars/servers
```

Yaml file is created as:

```
   ---
   ansible_ssh_user: root
```

Then:

```
ansible -m ping all
```

and the error that I encountered is as:

```
ERROR! Attempted to read "/etc/ansible/hosts" as YAML: Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/hosts': line 46, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

[Webserver]
192.168.27.1
^ here

Attempted to read "/etc/ansible/hosts" as ini file: /etc/ansible/hosts:50: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: 192.168.27.1
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks exactly like [this](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/58364/)
try to go into the file and search for a misplaced whitespace in that line.
The root cause was for a leading space in `/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts` file and the solution was searching for such spaces and remove them. The key part of the forum post is noted down below.

> This is caused by comments with leading whitespace in the `/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts` inventory file. This is new behavior for this Ansible version!
>
> So if you're in the habit of writing something like this in that hosts file:
>
> ```
> [web]
>      # legacy servers
>      webserver-[1:2].company.com
> ```
>
> Change it into:
>
> ```
> [web]
> # legacy servers
>      webserver-[1:2].company.com
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> [web]
>      webserver-[1:2].company.com # legacy servers
> ```